# How can we remove subquery here with good performance

Tags: sql

How can we remove sub-query here with good performance. If i am appending this sub-query it is giving correct output but slow down the search because of number of record available. But after removing this it's increases by multiple folds. Can anyone help in omitting this sub-query or anything to improve below query.

```
SELECT insurance_folder_cnt, MAX(lapsed_date) lapseddate 
FROM insurance_file ifl 
WHERE insurance_file_status_id=1 AND insurance_file_type_id in (2, 5, 6, 8, 9) AND (ISNULL(Base_Insurance_File_Cnt,0) = 0 OR ISNULL(Base_Insurance_File_Cnt, 0) = insurance_file_cnt) AND ISNULL(out_of_sequence_replaced, 0) = 0 
AND policy_version = (SELECT MAX(policy_version) FROM Insurance_File ifld WHERE ifl.insurance_folder_cnt=ifld.insurance_folder_cnt) GROUP BY insurance_folder_cnt having policy_version = max(policy_version)
```

Comment: To obtain better answer, please paste your quest as text. And better to provide the sample data, the execution plan.  Moreover, please state your database, `sql` is a language, but different RDMS may have different approach

Comment: SELECT insurance_folder_cnt, MAX(lapsed_date) lapseddate FROM insurance_file ifl
  WHERE insurance_file_status_id=1 AND insurance_file_type_id in (2, 5, 6, 8, 9) 
  AND (ISNULL(Base_Insurance_File_Cnt,0) = 0 OR ISNULL(Base_Insurance_File_Cnt, 0) = insurance_file_cnt)
  AND ISNULL(out_of_sequence_replaced, 0) = 0
  --AND policy_version = (SELECT MAX(policy_version) FROM Insurance_File ifld WHERE ifl.insurance_folder_cnt=ifld.insurance_folder_cnt)
  GROUP BY insurance_folder_cnt
  having policy_version = max(policy_version)

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Please [edit] your post instead of paste in comment

Comment: Sorry for this, I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use this for better performance:

SELECT  insurance_folder_cnt ,
        MAX(lapsed_date) lapseddate
FROM    insurance_file ifl
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    MAX(policy_version) AS maxVersion
                      FROM      Insurance_File ifld
                    ) TmpMaxVersion
WHERE   insurance_file_status_id = 1
        AND insurance_file_type_id IN ( 2, 5, 6, 8, 9 )
        AND ( ISNULL(Base_Insurance_File_Cnt, 0) = 0
              OR ISNULL(Base_Insurance_File_Cnt, 0) = insurance_file_cnt
            )
        AND ISNULL(out_of_sequence_replaced, 0) = 0
        AND policy_version = TmpMaxVersion.maxVersion
GROUP BY insurance_folder_cnt
HAVING  policy_version = MAX(policy_version)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
SELECT insurance_folder_cnt, MAX(lapsed_date) lapseddate 
FROM insurance_file ifl 
join (select insurance_folder_cnt inffld, max(policy_version) pol_ver from insurace_file group by insurance_folder_cnt) ifld 
on (ifld.inffld = ifl.insurance_folder_cnt and pol_ver = ifl.policy_version)
WHERE insurance_file_status_id=1 AND insurance_file_type_id in (2, 5, 6, 8, 9)
 AND (ISNULL(Base_Insurance_File_Cnt,0) = 0 OR ISNULL(Base_Insurance_File_Cnt, 0) = insurance_file_cnt) 
 AND ISNULL(out_of_sequence_replaced, 0) = 0 
 GROUP BY insurance_folder_cnt
```

you can also replace ISNULL function:

```
(Base_Insurance_File_Cnt is null OR Base_Insurance_File_Cnt = insurance_file_cnt)
```